# Adding multiple text overlay on shapes in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, overlay, shapes

I am working on a project where I use different shapes in SwiftUI, for example, this RoundedRectangle. **I want to add text on it through overlay but it doesn’t let me add more than one line**. I tried to search for some tutorials for overlay but always found ones showing just -one life of text - example.

**So I was wondering if there’s a way to add multiple lines of text overlay on shapes like that or if there is some better way to approach it.**

Thank you for your feedback.

Here’s the current code:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .frame(width: 320, height: 200)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .overlay(
                Text("Hello there")
           )
            
      }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And here’s what I would ideally like, but this way it doesn’t work this way:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .frame(width: 320, height: 200)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .overlay(
                Text("Hello there")
                Text("Hello there")
                Text("Hello there")
                Text("Hello there")
                Text("Hello there")
                Text("Hello there")
                
           )
            
      }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapped your text with anyone of them `Group`, `VStack`, `HStack`, etc. in one container.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
           HStack {
           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
               .frame(width: 320, height: 200)
               .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
               .overlay(
                Group{ //<-- Here
                   Text("Hello there")
                   Text("Hello there")
                   Text("Hello there")
                   Text("Hello there")
                   Text("Hello there")
                   Text("Hello there")
                }
              )
         }
       }
}
```

---

Or you can use `@ViewBuilder`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
           HStack {
           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
               .frame(width: 320, height: 200)
               .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
               .overlay(
                overlayView
              )
         }
       }
    
    // Make your view here
    @ViewBuilder
    private var overlayView: some View {
        Text("Hello there")
        Text("Hello there")
        Text("Hello there")
        Text("Hello there")
        Text("Hello there")
        Text("Hello there")
    }
}
```